# Python global namespaces and evaluation order

Tags: python, namespaces, global

Try this out:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = A + B

def main():
    global C
    print A
```

The output of `main()` is `1`.

Why is this? Why should `main` get to know about the other global variables used to evaluate `C`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Global variables are always available to all local scopes in Python, including functions. In this case, within `main()` `A`, `B`, and `C` are all in scope.

The `global` keyword doesn't do what it seems you think it does; rather, it permits a local scope to manipulate a global function (it makes global variables "writable", so to speak). Consider these examples:

```
c = 4
print c
def foo():
    c = 3
    print c
foo()
print c
```

Here, the output will be

```
4
3
4
```

Now, consider this:

```
c = 4
print c
def foo():
    global c
    c = 3
    print c
foo()
print c
```

In this case, the output will be

```
4
3
3
```

In the first case, `c = 3` merely shadows `c` until its scope is up (i.e. when the function definition ends). In the second case, we're actually referring to a reference to a global `c` after we write `global c`, so changing the value of `c` will lead to a permanent change.

Comment: additional documentation: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Comment: This answer doesn't make it clear that "global" is all about writing variables, not about reading them.

Answer (score 4):

Functions can read variables in enclosing scopes.  The [global declaration](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) is used to writing variables (to indiciate that they should be written to the global dictionary rather than the local dictionary).